# Adding an arrow over the polyline in mkmapkit?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mkmapview, mkpolyline

I had an application in which i am showing polylines in mkmapkit like this -

```
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:4];
//[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]]; //If you want the route to be visible

[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];

-(MKPolylineRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        if(nil == self.routeLineView)
        {
            self.routeLineView = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine];
            self.routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            self.routeLineView.lineWidth = 2;

        }

        return self.routeLineView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Now i want to add an arrow over that polylines to show the direction  like this

> [How to draw an arrow on every polyline segment on Google Maps V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305497/how-to-draw-an-arrow-on-every-polyline-segment-on-google-maps-v3)

. I googled for the same but no luck so far. Can anybody direct me on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest actually drawing the arrow yourself with an MKOverlayPathRenderer, as I do in this example:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve, but the point of MKOverlayPathRenderer is that it just draws a CGPath. So if you can draw it, you can display it on the map.

Comment: i want to achieve like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305497/how-to-draw-an-arrow-on-every-polyline-segment-on-google-maps-v3

Comment: Well, you know the coordinates on the map (because that's where the end of the line is), so just draw the arrow at that place.

Comment: i  joined the 3 points through polylines(in our case not route just straight lines ,but i need to place a forward arrow at the middle of that each poliline.is that possible inside that polyline
)

Comment: can u pls add an answer with arrow drawing code over that lines ?